# Python PDF-Redactor only partially mask content

Tags: python, regex, pdf, lambda, filtering

I'm using the python PDF redactor and it works great: 
https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor

The syntax for masking content as specified in the github looks like this, where the regex is the pattern to find and the X's in the lambda expression is the string to replace the found patterns with:

```
options.content_filters = [
    (
        re.compile(r"5555-(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{6})"),
        lambda m : "XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXX"
    )
]
```

But what if I want to find the expression matching that, and only mask everything but the last four characters, something like this:

```
options.content_filters = [
    (
        re.compile(r"5555-(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{6})"),
        lambda m : "XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXRRRR"
    )
]
```

Where 'R' would denote keep the original character. I can't find any documentation in the github on how to do this, or use some built in regex / lamda functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may re-group the patterns to capture what you need to keep, and make use of the match data object, `m`:

```
options.content_filters = [
    (
        re.compile(r"5555-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}(\d{4})"),
        lambda m : "XXXX-XXX-XXX-XX" + m.group(1)
    )
]
```

Here, `5555-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}` matches `5555-`, three digits, `-`, three digits, `-`, two digits, and `(\d{4})` captures four digits in Group 1. You may access that value using `m.group(1)`.

If you plan to match these codes as whole words. Consider using

- `r"\b5555-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}(\d{4})\b"`
- `r"(?<!\d)5555-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}(\d{4})(?!\d)"`
- `r"(?<!\d)(?<!\d-)5555-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}(\d{4})(?!-?\d)"`